# Why does my expl3 \prop_item increment my \stepcounter?

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, counters, expl3, l3prop

### What I'm trying to do

I want to create a custom cross-referencing tag which a reader can click on and view the line of text I am referencing.  However, I want the numbering of the tags to be automated so I can add and subtract items from my text without manually renumbering something.

To achieve this, I am currently kludging together an `expl3` `\prop_` which behaves similarly to the Python `dict` or C-like `map` which are quite common.  I set and call my custom tags inside commands and spit out a test.  BUT, it seems like my `\prop_item` increments my counter in a manner I don't expect.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xparse}

% Define a dict-like object where I can store the label and my associated text.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_prop_dict
\NewDocumentCommand{\dictappend}{mm}{%
  \prop_gput:Nnn\g_prop_dict{#1}{#2}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\CGet}{m}{%
  \prop_item:Nn\g_prop_dict{#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% First counter
\newcounter{articlejournal}
\setcounter{articlejournal}{1}
\newcommand{\countAJ}[1]{%
    \dictappend{#1}{AJ\thearticlejournal}
    \phantomsection\label{#1}{\textbf{AJ\thearticlejournal}}
    \stepcounter{articlejournal}
}% 

% Secound counter
\newcounter{articleconference}
\setcounter{articleconference}{1}
\newcommand{\countAC}[1]{%
    \dictappend{#1}{AC\thearticleconference}
    \phantomsection\label{#1}{\textbf{AC\thearticleconference}}
    \stepcounter{articleconference}
}% 

% Command to retrieve the value and format it correctly.
\newcommand{\myref}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\textbf{\CGet{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\countAJ{foo} - is test 1

\countAJ{bar} - is test 2

\countAC{baz} - this is a different one

Here I reference \myref{bar} and \myref{foo}, and here I want \myref{baz}.

I expect these to look like AJ2, AJ1, and AC1, respectively.
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Making Input Variables Immutable

It seems like my `\dictappend{#1}{A*\thearticle***}` formatted lines are not passing immutable values with `\the` like I would expect.  Is that not how it works?

### What I Don't Want or Does not Work

- I have tried using parts from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321868/concatenate-macro-string-and-counter), but no configuration helped that I tried.  This is odd, because @egreg 's answer seems like it should work when I apply it to `\dictappend{#1}{\edef\newstring{AJ\thearticlejournal}}`, yet this just makes my string disappear.
- Making a 2-argument label definition a la [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254869/referencing-custom-counter) is not acceptable here.  I want to be able to insert a new entry into a big list without re-numbering things manually.  My use-case requires self-reference.
- Since I have multiple counters I want to reference with `\myref`, using `\the` to access the count does not have the effect I need [as cited here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655315/referencing-a-custom-counter-cross-referencing).  Using `\the` alone, the best I could manage was injection of the counter value only.
- Similarly, working with `\refstepcounter` similar to [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/441971/labelling-and-referencing-multiple-custom-counters-together) only returns the value instead of the text.

### The Ask

Why are my variables incrementing during this operation?  How can I fix this such that they do not change after each dict entry is defined?

Comment: I did not examine this thoroughly, but a hunch is that you actually want to use `\prop_gput:Nnx` in `\dictappend`.

Comment: `\dictappend{#1}{A*\thearticle***}` just stores `A*\thearticle***`  you want an `x` or `e` variant to expand the argument

Comment: @gusbrs Your hunch seems correct.  Write that up for your magic internet points.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can get the ``x`` to work like gusbrs mentioned, but using the nested ``e`` in the arg-spec ``:Nne`` in the ``_gput`` appears to fail.

Comment: `e` variant of that one isn't predefined but you can always define such variants, just a representative sample are predefined, more `x` than `e` as the `e` type is newer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you store the value of your counter in the property list with:

```tex
\NewDocumentCommand{\dictappend}{mm}{%
  \prop_gput:Nnn\g_prop_dict{#1}{#2}
}
```

Then use `\dictappend` in `\countAJ` as:

```tex
\dictappend{#1}{AJ\thearticlejournal}
```

You are storing `AJ\thearticlejournal` with "no manipulation", given the `n` signature in `\prop_gput:Nnn`.

When you use this value in `\CGet` then `AJ\thearticlejournal` is expanded, in other words, you get the current value for `\thearticlejournal` in the place you called `\CGet` (and `\myref`).

If you want this value to be the one at the point you have stored it, then you need to expand it at that point. Which you can do by using `\prop_gput:Nnx` instead of `\prop_gput:Nnn` in `\dictappend`:

```tex
\NewDocumentCommand{\dictappend}{mm}{%
  \prop_gput:Nnx\g_prop_dict{#1}{#2}
}
```